# SQL Server doesn't get date format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format, sql-insert

I'm trying to INSERT date variable into my SQL server.
The input format I'm trying to insert is: dd-mm-yyyy
And my SQL server column (which defined as type DATE) expect mm-dd-yyyy.

My PC date format is dd-mm-yyyy.

The error msg:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Questions:

1. Why is the expected format mm-dd-yyyy and not dd-mm-yyyy?
2. How can I make the INSERT command work with this or another date format?

Thanks.

Comment: HOW are you trying to insert rows into your table? Dates have a non-readable binary format inside the db engine.

Answer (score 1):

The format that your PC uses for dates doesn't matter when passing literal string for dates, the language setting for the `LOGIN`  you are using to connect to SQL Server does. As the value is being interpreted as `MM-dd-yyyy` this very likely means that your language setting is (American) `ENGLISH`.

If, therefore, you are the only person that uses that `LOGIN` you may well want to change the language of your `LOGIN` to be appropriate for yourself. Most of the European languages, including `BRITISH` English (because the British don't speak English Microsoft? ) use the format `dd-MM-yyyy`.

*Really*, however, what you should be doing is using an unambiguous date format, of which there are only 2 in SQL Server, regardless of the language setting and data type. Those 2 formats are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. If you are *always* using the newer date and time data types (so not `datetime` or `smalldatetime`), then `yyyy-MM-dd( hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn)` is also unambiguous, however, as it's language specific for the older data type then I don't normally recommend it's use.

Storage wise, date and time data types don't have a format, so your column isn't "expected" a value in the format `MM-dd-yyyy`, as it doesn't retain the "format data" that the value was passed in. Again, the only reason why a value like `13-12-2020` is working is because your language setting, which uses `mdy` for date interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Two things really,

Firstly, you can control the expected date format for each connection. Before issuing the insert statement, do `set dateformat dmy;` or `set dateformat mdy;` as appropriate.

Secondly, it's always advisable to work with dates in the ISO format of YYYYMMDD, so if you insert the data '20210314' it will always be treated correctly.